# How to connect input and three.js canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

This is STL Viewer:

```
import * as THREE from "https://threejs.org/build/three.module.js";
import {OrbitControls} from "https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";
import {STLLoader} from "https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/loaders/STLLoader.js";

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xafdafc );
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas:test});
renderer.setSize(500, 500);
const loader = new STLLoader();
loader.load('./model.stl', function (geometry) {
    const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
        color: 0xe6e6fa,
        emissive: 0x2b2b2b,
        specular: 0xe6e6e6,
        metalness: 1,
        roughness: 0.8,
    });
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(mesh);
});

const spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xeeeece);
spotLight.position.set(1000, 1000, 1000);
scene.add(spotLight);

const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
camera.position.set(0, 20, 100);
controls.update();

function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
render();
```

And this HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="file" id="button" class="button">
    <script src="js/index.js" type="module"></script>
    <canvas class="test" id="test"></canvas>
</form>
```

how to connect `<input>` and `three.js`? I want to use the button to upload any STL model to canvas. I trying use `input.addEventListener`, but it's not working. Mby i do something wrong.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not working"? Do you get error messages? Does anything happen at all? Have you tried debugging and if so, where does the program get stuck/start to act unexpected?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that I don't know how to do it. I tried to intuitively get into the syntax, because I didn't find any examples, but it didn't work. Errors referred to the module code Three.js, not my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a full working example that shows the basic workflow: https://jsfiddle.net/17q6b2sd/2/

First, you need a respective input tag:

```
<input id="input" type="file">
```

In your JS code, you then have to add an event listener to this element which process the selected file. As you can see, the code uses the `FileReader` API for this:

```js
var input = document.getElementById( 'input' );
input.addEventListener( 'change', function( event ) {
    
    var file = this.files[ 0 ];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    
    reader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {

        var contents = event.target.result;

        var geometry = new STLLoader().parse( contents );
        var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial();
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        
        mesh.castShadow = true;
        mesh.receiveShadow = true;
        
        scene.add( mesh );

    }, false );
    
    if ( reader.readAsBinaryString !== undefined ) {

        reader.readAsBinaryString( file );

    } else {

        reader.readAsArrayBuffer( file );

    }
    
} );
```

Similar code is used in the [three.js editor](https://threejs.org/editor/) which does not read files via an input element but via drag'n'drop.

BTW: I've tested the fiddle with this STL file: [slotted_disk.stl](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/models/stl/ascii/slotted_disk.stl)

Comment: Thx! one more question - how can I clear the scene before loading the model? Now each new model is placed on the stage along with the old one.

Comment: I suggest you traverse through the scene via `Object3D.traverse()` and dispose all materials and geometries. Finally, you remove the object. More information in this forum topic: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-completely-clean-up-a-three-js-scene-from-a-web-app-once-the-scene-is-no-longer-needed/1549/11?u=mugen87